# Fluentbit does not parse square brackets

Tags: regex, parsing, fluent-bit

I am trying to parse following line

`2021-03-09 05:31:41.396 [main] INFO  [][][] o.s.c.b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration - Located property source: [BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-configmap.aa.default'}]`

with this regex

`^(?<time>\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d) \[(?<thread>[^ ]+)\] (?<severity>[^ ]+) \[\]\[(?<request_id>[^ ]*)\]\[\] (?<class>[^ :]*) - (?<log>.*)$`

everything works up until `\[\]\[(?<request_id>[^ ]*)\]\[\]` - adding request_id results in creating a mapping on elasticsearch which puts everything under log property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(?<time>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}) +\[(?<thread>[^ ]+)\] +(?<severity>[^ ]+) +\[\]\[(?<request_id>[^ ]*)\]\[\] +(?<class>[^ :]*) +- +(?<log>.*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YQ6dIo/1).

There are multiple spaces between `INFO` and `[][][]`, so you need to use `+` to quantify the space. Also, you need to escape the dot that must match a literal dot. Also, repeating `\d` four times is not pretty, that is why you resort to *limiting* (or *range*) quantifiers, `{4}` matches `\d` four times.